# How to pass dynamic values in sql in cube.js schema?

Tags: cube.js

Somewhere I want status=2 or status<3. Instead of writing separate schemas, how to reuse by passing dynamic values to the status field in SQL?

```
cube(`OrderFacts`, {
  sql: `SELECT * FROM orders WHERE status>3`, // <--- I want to pass dynamic values to the condition

  measures: {
    count: {
      type: `count`
    }
  },

  dimensions: {
    date: {
      sql: `date`,
      type: `time`
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the [Unsafe Value section](https://cube.dev/docs/cube#context-variables-unsafe-value) of the Context Variables documentation:

```
cube(`Orders`, {
  sql: `SELECT * FROM orders WHERE status > ${SECURITY_CONTEXT.status.unsafeValue()`,
});
```

Generally speaking, it's best not to do this though; instead I'd recommend using [segments](https://cube.dev/docs/segments#top) to achieve the same functionality (assuming there aren't a lot of values for `status`)